# Sum values based on criteria in alternate column

Tags: excel, vba, range

I need to subtotal the timing in column C that relates to multiple delivery scenarios of a learning course. The delivery methods are listed in column G and could be Deliver, Recap, Reinforcement or Consolidation.

I have a static SUMIF formula (e.g. =SUMIF(G5:G15, "Deliver", C5:C15)) which I have the macro input to the relevant summary cell, which I have in the code like this:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
  "=SUMIF(R[-2]C:R[-1]C, ""Deliver"", R[-2]C[-4]:R[-1]C[-4])"
```

I had it count up only a couple of rows because the training plan changes in length each time, so I need the range to be variable. I reset the range manually after I run the macro.

The summary timings in the sheet look like this:
[image]

I have read a few posts here about selecting a variable range but I haven't been able to convert any to my situation.

How do I write the code so the macro works out the new range for each training plan length so I don't need to manually update?

I'm very new to VBA.

Comment: Is there always at least one empty cell below the data in column **G** ??

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your help. Yes there is, the summary lines in the example are the bottom of the data. All cells below are empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by fixing the initial cells in the formula to absolute references, e.g.:
 "=SUMIF(R5C7:R[-7]C, ""Consolidation"", R5C3:R[-7]C[-4])"